# How do I know if an object is inside the view frustum of a camera in blender (bpy)?

Tags: blender, bpy

I have a sphere object and I need to know if it is inside the view frustum of my camera. I use blender version 2.8 and I am looking for a scripting solution with bpy. Is there a function similar to insideFrustum(object, camera)?

For blender 2.79 there was a function sphereInsideFrustum(..) for controller.owner objects of the logic class.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sphereInsideFrustum`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79b/bge.types.KX_Camera.html#bge.types.KX_Camera.sphereInsideFrustum) was part of the game engine which is no longer a part of blender. If you are looking for a real-time solution you will need to look at alternative game engines.

If you search blender.stackexchange for [pixel+scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=pixel%20scene) you will find several answers about associating geometry with the final rendered image.

Comment: I just need to make sure, that when I add an object with blender python it is inside the view of the camera used to render the pictures. I went over to blender.stackexchange and searched for pixel+scene, but I could not find a similar question.

Comment: I think there have been questions about going the way you want but I can't seem to find them. While not a python solution, there are ways to [see in the viewport](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/61215/935) what is visible, although Rays solution of modeling a box to match the viewable area could give you a point in box solution.